# Got a Trojan with Tor download

Tags: malware

I used the link from the Tor newsletter to get the latest version of Tor. When I installed and then launched it, I got an alert that there was a Trojan virus. My antivirus killed it and it hasn't popped up again.

So, my question is - how did I get a Trojan virus from downloading Tor?

Comment: Could you post the download link?

Comment: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-weekly-news-%E2%80%94-february-12th-2014: The Tor Browser team delivers a new Tor Browser Bundle >> https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html

Answer (score 4):

I have heard of antivirus software wrongly flagging Tor in the past because it's used by some viruses. That could be the case here.

You should check the digital signature of your downloaded Tor browser bundle file.
There are some videos describing how to do that [here](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) under the heading "How to verify the digital signatures". It's also described [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) if you prefer to read.

If the signature is *correct* then it's almost certain you have a legitimate copy of Tor.
If the signature is *incorrect* then you've got yourself a bad copy of Tor, although it's not clear how.